# Multiple spring dependencies of different versions

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies, pom.xml

I am working with spring-boot and want to include two different versions of spring-web in my project since one of the APIs in the latest version has been deprecated. In order to continue using that, I have included two dependencies of spring-web with different versions but eclipse is recognizing only of them.

I have tried excluding almost everything from the older version of spring-web but that doesn't seems to work either- any way out please?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.springsource.com.caucho</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You cannot depend on multiple versions of the same dependency. That does not make sense. How would you know which one has to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to have two different versions of a dependency in your project because of a Maven concept called 'D*ependency Mediation*'. Have a look at the [Maven Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) documentation.

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency
>   will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered.
>   Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition"
>   which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to
>   your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a
>   version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if
>   two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree,
>   until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since
>   Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first
>   declaration wins.